# Java generics and type inference

Tags: java, generics

From [Sun Tutorials for generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)

Type Inference

> To illustrate this last point, in the following example, inference
>   determines that the second argument being passed to the pick method is
>   of type String:

```
static <T> T pick(T a1, T a2) { return a2; }  
Serializable s = pick("d", new ArrayList<String>());
```

Origirally I thought that the idea is that you could use any parameter in place of `T` as long as it ends up with `String`. Example `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

But then I saw that the following also compiled fine:
`Serializable s = pick("d", new ArrayList<Integer>());`
It seems that `T` is inferred to be a `Serializable` and not a `String`?

So what is the meaning of the statement

> inference determines that the second argument being passed to the pick
>   method is **of type String**

Comment: @assylias:The most general form should be infered, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the 3 types are `Serializable`, `String`, `ArrayList<String>`.

- `Serializable` does not extend anything
- `String` implements `Serializable` and other unrelated stuff
- `ArrayList<String>` implements `Serializable` and other unrelated stuff

So the most specific type that applies to all 3 is `Serializable`.

If you replace the call with `Serializable s = pick("d", new Object());` for example, it does not compile any longer because the most specific type is now Object and you can't cast Object to Serializable.

Comment: 1)Don't you mean `ArrayList<E>` implements `Serializable`?2) The most specific or the most generic type?

Comment: 1) Yes ArrayList<Anything> implements Serializable 2) the most specific that applies to all 3. In your case, all three types are also Objects, but Serializable is more specific than Object so that's what is chosen.

Comment: If I change to: `String s = pick("d", new ArrayList<String>());` it also does not compile.But this case is not clear why.It says: `cannot convert from Serializable to String`. How did it infer `Serializable` from this?All are `String`s

Comment: Because Serializable is the most specific common supertype of both String and ArrayList.

Comment: Walk upwards the type hierarchy starting from `Serializable`, `String`, `ArrayList<String>` until you hit a common ancestor.